# Why do we write $df/dx$ instead of $df/dx(x)$?

Tags: derivatives, notation

I was just thinking about how, i.e., if $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is defined by $f(x) = x^2$, then it's customary to write
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = 2x.
$$
But since the derivative is itself a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$, shouldn't we write
$$
\frac{df}{dx}(x) = 2x?
$$
After all, we would typically write $f'(x) = 2x$, not just $f' = 2x$, right?

Comment: it is just a short notation,you can write both of them

Comment: @VincenzoOliva I wrote $f$ to denote the function, $f(x)$ to denote its value at the point $x$.

Comment: When writing $\frac{df}{dx}$ the $x$ in $dx$ + $d$ instead of $\partial$ tells us that $x$ is the (and only) variable so there is not really a need for the $(x)$. In general if there is no explicit need for such a thing it tends to get omitted. That happens quite often with notation; people tend to go for the minimal way of presenting equations. You are of course free to use it if you feel like it.

Comment: If $f(x)=x^2,$ then we should write $(df/dx)(a) = 2a.$ But we don't, instead letting $x$ signify two or three different things. We get used to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your objection, I prefer: if $u = f(x)=x^2$, then
$$
\frac{du}{dx} = x^2 \qquad \text{and}\qquad f'(x)=x^2
$$
Or even
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\big(x^2) = 2x
$$
Then (if you like) you can avoid both
$$
\frac{df}{dx} = x^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad\frac{df}{dx}(x) = 2x
$$

Comment: Not sure I see the point of $u$ in the first part.